# Is there a way to access the (I)DFT matrix of a Fourier transform in FFTW?

Tags: fftw

In [FFTW](https://fftw.org/), is there a way to access the [(I)DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) of a Fourier transform executed by a given [plan](https://fftw.org/doc/Using-Plans.html)? I can't find any leads in the [documentation](https://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/) so I am not sure whether it is exposed to the user.